# Django REST Framework HyperlinkedModelSerializer write operations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my project I'm using a OneToOneField with user to add the field 'screen_name'.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
```

From this I would like to create a resource 'player' using django REST framework to edit both the user information and 'screen_name' in a transparent mannor.

Looking through the internet I have found that writing a custom serializer is probably the way forward, but I could not find on the docs how to combine two models, or use a Hyperlinked serializer.

I have at the moment:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    # I need some bad ass code here to link through the 'User' model data so I can do 
      proxy POST GET DEL operations through the 'Player' resource

    class Meta:
    model = Player
    fields = ('screen_name','username','password','email','first_name', 'last_name')
```

Has anyone got any code they could show me that can do something similar?

Comment: Can you give us example POST data body?

Answer (score 0):

I think the HyperlinkedModelSerializer is reasonably documented here:

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#hyperlinkedmodelserializer

...may not have been when you last searched.

**Disclaimer: I am not a programmer or a rest_framework expert**

I could be on the totally wrong path here, but I feel a bit like the two things you are linking are different URIs - i.e. different resources in the www - and should probably be treated as such (unless you really don't need to separate the two things in the back-end).

I don't mean that you should force a crappy experience on the consumer of your to-be-beautifully-RESTful API. I think you may be better off creating a function/method that can receive the data you are after in one call and then it can manage the object manipulation server-side.

I am interested in views on this approach as I have made the decision to manage things this way for myself. I feel that it helps maintain the separation of the URIs and better abstracts any underlying complexity allowing for independent change of either URI.